# Not able to add scrollable confirmDialog with dimention

Tags: jsf, primefaces, scrollable, confirm-dialog

I have to display one scrollable confirmDialog with fixed width and height.
I am trying it by this way:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="ui_confirm_dialog" header="Confirmation" severity="info"
    widgetVar="ui_confirm_dialog_Var" max-width="700" max-height="10" scrollable="true">
```

This is not working as expected. How can I achieve this?

Comment: <p:confirmDialog id="_ui_confirm_dialog" header="Confirmation" severity="info" widgetVar="_ui_confirm_dialog_Var" max-width="700" max-height="10" scrollable="true">

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: You expectations are wrong... Solution: put a panel in there and make that scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Based on their documentation - http://www.primefaces.org/documentation,
**there are no** max-height, max-width and scrollable attributes on that component.

You can specify dimensions by using height and width:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="_ui_confirm_dialog" header="Confirmation"
 severity="info" widgetVar="_ui_confirm_dialog_Var" width="700" height="10">
```

But as of specification you cannot make it scrollable, unless you would write your own custom / composite component on top of what primefaces offer.